# Responsive Topbar

Tags: html, css, templates, slider

I have 2 navbar which is Top Bar and Menu, The menu is responsive but Top Bar not. How I make a responsive top bar (icon and image)?

```
<div class="header widget-style1 clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-wrap clearfix">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4" style="float: right;">
                            <div id="" class="">
                                <a href="/" rel="home">

                                    <img src="{{asset('images/logojipp34.jpg')}}" alt="image">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /. -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="page" style="margin-top: 50px"> 
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                        <a href="" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color: #9D2629"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                        <a href="" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f fa-2x" style="color: #9D2629"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                        <a href="" class="social-media"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color: #9D2629"></i></a>
                                    </div>                                
                                </div>                                    
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.header-wrap -->
        </div>
```

how I make responsive design with that?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you add something like

```css
body {margin:0;}

.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.topbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">FAQ</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mean on <div class="col-lg-8"> above

Comment: read updated answer
also, add all of your css in `<style>/* enter code here*/</style>` or `<style src=example.css>` or it may break in some browsers

Comment: did you find a solution?